# How to align boxes in two column mode

Tags: beamer, columns

I am using two columns as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=5mm} 
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tcolorbox}[text width=\textwidth-1cm, text height=2.5cm]{}

\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[top=0pt, left=5pt,right=5pt, colback=blue!5!white, text width=4.7cm, text height=4.3cm]

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]

\begin{itemize}
\item Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui 
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  v
\item Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium 
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I:

- Line up the left hand edges of the boxes
- Make as much room as possible for the right hand column but not have the bullet circles too close to the box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `columns` environment is wider than regular text. If you want to use one column and two columns environments in one slide, you can add option `onlytextwidth` to `columns` declaration, like in following example. Another solution would be to declare the one column fragment inside a `columns` environment, this way both would use similar width.

In you `tcolorboxes` you make a mistake fixing `text width`. This parameter is no the width of the total box, but the width of the text inside it. Therefore your boxes are wider than expected. This is the reason for items dots appearing over the left box. Default total width of tcolorboxes is all the available `textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=5mm} 
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tcolorbox}[text height=2.5cm]{}

\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}

\begin{tcolorbox}[top=0pt, left=5pt,right=5pt, colback=blue!5!white, text height=4.3cm]

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]

\begin{itemize}
\item Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui 
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod v
\item Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium 
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I always find I need more space on the slide so ways of making small adjustments are of great value to me.